# Get bundler to install gem for specific platform

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

I use the 'fluent-logger' gem for logging in our project, which needs 'msgpack'. If I run `bundle install` it pulls in `msgpack-1.1.0-x86-mingw32`, which throws an exception when requiring it on Windows.

```
kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/msgpack (LoadError)
```

But there exists a workaround for the problem, by just reinstalling the gem with `--platform=ruby` like this:

```
gem uninstall msgpack
gem install msgpack --platform=ruby
```

I tried to put this requirement into the Gemfile as indicated elsewhere (can't find the link atm), but it didn't do anything (installed `msgpack-1.1.0-x86-mingw32` as before):

```
gem 'msgpack', :platforms=>:ruby
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p551 (and bundler v 1.14.6) on Windows 7, in case that matters.

## Edit

To allow everyone who wants, to try it themselves I give an example source.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'fluent-logger'
gem 'msgpack', :platforms=>:ruby_19 
#for windows local dev msgpack needs to be installed with --platform=ruby
```

foo.rb

```
require 'fluent-logger'

logger= Fluent::Logger::FluentLogger.new
#logger.post('idx',{message:'it works'})
puts 'worked'
```

The logger won't create a valid connection, but if it runs through that's great
(The only important thing here is that the Gemfile doesn't pull in the right version of msgpack (in my case `1.1.0-x86-mingw32` instead of `1.1.0`))

Answer (score 2):

http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html

Copy and pasted from the above:

> You can restrict further by platform and version for all platforms except for rbx, jruby, and mswin.
>
> To specify a version in addition to a platform, append the version number without the delimiter to the platform. For example, to specify that a gem should only be used on platforms with Ruby 2.3, use:
>
> ruby_23
>
> The full list of platforms and supported versions includes:
>
> ruby
> 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5
>
> mri
> 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5
>
> mingw
> 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5
>
> x64_mingw
> 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5
> As with groups, you can specify one or more platforms:
>
> gem "weakling",   :platforms => :jruby
>
> gem "ruby-debug", :platforms => :mri_18
>
> gem "nokogiri",   :platforms => [:mri_18, :jruby]

So in your case, try

```
gem 'msgpack', :platforms=>:ruby_19
```

Comment: Thanks for the manpage (i missed that one), but unfortunately it pulls in the same gem as before  

    `λ bundle show msgpack
    D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/msgpack-1.1.0-x86-mingw32`
and that leads to the same error as before  

    `D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/msgpack (LoadError)`

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old by now, but I had a similar problem and thought other people might run across this in looking for an answer.

As I understand it, the Gemfile `platforms` option only allows excluding gems; it does not affect whether the gem will be compiled natively or the precompiled version will be fetched, just whether it will be installed on a given platform.

The way to tell bundler to build the gem natively even if a precompiled version is available is to add the `force_ruby_platform` option, like this:

```
gem 'msgpack', force_ruby_platform: true
```

See the [man page](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/gemfile.5.html#FORCE_RUBY_PLATFORM).